# mongo: finding missing documents by propery value

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections with documents of identical schema.  Let's call them collections A (with documents {a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>,...,a<sub>m</sub>}) and B (with documents {b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>,...,b<sub>n</sub>}).  Is there a way to construct a mongo query such that it returns a set of documents {a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>,.., a<sub>k</sub>} from collection A where a<sub>i<m</sub>[p]  ∉ UNIQUE(b<sub>j<n</sub>[p])?

In reality collection B has a few dozen million records and collection A has several hundred million records.  I can't figure out how to do this efficiently.